# Is there any way to create a Pivot Table in Excel using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I am currently working on the automation of Excel, and add such I have made a good use of the Apache  POI library.

As I have so much data stored in my excel workbook in various columns, that I'm trying to create a pivot table.

**Is there any way to create Pivot tables using POI ?**

My requirement is that I need to create the pivot table in a new excel workbook or in the same workbook where I  store my data.

Comment: Hey have you seen the update?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The 'Quick Guide' is quite out of date.

The [change log](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html) refers to this [bugzilla issue](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56020) as resolved.

You can see the code [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/CreatePivotTable.java):

Here is a snippet:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet();

        //Create some data to build the pivot table on
        setCellData(sheet);

        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference("A1:D4"), new CellReference("H5"));
        //Configure the pivot table
        //Use first column as row label
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
        //Sum up the second column
        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
        //Set the third column as filter
        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 2);
        //Add filter on forth column
        pivotTable.addReportFilter(3);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pivottable.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
```

Comment: can you please add list of jar files, because I am unable to find required for XSSFPivotTable and DataConsolidateFunction

Comment: @ashishbalchandi what version of POI do you have?

Comment: @ashishbalchandi try upgrading,  and adding it to the class path/build path

Comment: yes, but latest stable version is Apache POI 3.10.1, which I already have. B/w what version you have in your system??

Comment: @ashishbalchandi a much older version, as we don't use xlsx. Make sure that the class you're using is XSSFWorkbook, the Workbook interface won't have pivot methods.

Comment: yes its XSSFWorkbook only and I have added all jars- commons-codec-1.5.jar,commons-logging-1.1.jar,dom4j-1.6.1.jar,junit-4.11.jar,log4j-1.2.13.jar,poi-3.10.1-20140818.jar,poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20140818.jar,poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1-20140818.jar, stax-api-1.0.1.jar and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

Comment: @ashishbalchandi it looks like you have a dev build jar (based on the datestamp 20140818)

Comment: @ashishbalchandi not that I know of

Comment: Anyways Thanks @Pureferret Its been so long i had risen this issue.. I ll work again on it.! and come back with issues..:P

Answer (score 1):

No you cant.refer [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html)

> • Charts   You can not currently create charts. You can however create
>   a chart in Excel, modify the chart data values using HSSF and write a
>   new spreadsheet out. This is possible because POI attempts to keep
>   existing records intact as far as possible.
>
> • Macros   Macros can not be created. However, reading and re-writing
>   files containing macros will safely preserve the macros.
>
> • Pivot Tables   Generating pivot tables is not supported. It has been
>   reported that files containing pivot tables can be read and re-written
>   safely.

Comment: This is no longer correct - XSSF now supports creating Pivot tables, as the page you link to current says

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create. Dependency required

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Input Excel file

[image]

Java code to create pivot table on same sheet

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        /* Read the input file that contains the data to pivot */
        FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("input-file-path\\Pivot-Cube.xlsx"));
        /* Create a POI XSSFWorkbook Object from the input file */
        XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document);
        /* Read Data to be Pivoted - we have only one worksheet */
        XSSFSheet sheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        /* Get the reference for Pivot Data */
        AreaReference a=new AreaReference("A1:C5");
        /* Find out where the Pivot Table needs to be placed */
        CellReference b=new CellReference("I5");
       

        /* Create Pivot Table */
        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(a,b, sheet);
        /* Add filters */
        pivotTable.addReportFilter(0);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2);
        /* Write Pivot Table to File */
        FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("output-file-path\\POI_XLS_Pivot_Example.xlsx"));
        my_xlsx_workbook.write(output_file);
        input_document.close();
    }


}
```